# Compiler complains about wrong type, but it is clearly correct

Tags: android, kotlin

I have the following issue with Kotlin, here is my code:

```
val dishesBitmaps: LiveData<List<Bitmap>> = liveData {
    val data = getDishesBitmaps()
    data?.let {
        emit(data)
    }
}
```

`getDishesBitmaps()` returns `List<Bitmap>?` however, the compiler shows me the following error

> Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is LiveData?> but LiveData> was expected

but `data` clearly becomes `List<Bitmap>` after the null check. The strange thing is that it compiles fine if I explicitly cast it like this `emit(data as List<Bitmap>)` (but again IDE shows that the cast is not needed).

Is this a bug in the compiler or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you change the code to `emit(it)`, does the error go away?

Comment: @CommonsWare yes, with `emit(it)` it compiles

Comment: Have you tried to force the type : val data : List<Bitmap>= getDishesBitmaps()

Comment: @XavierBouclet well, as I said, if I force the type it works. That suprised me is that IDE and the compiler behave differently in this case, analyzing the code

Comment: I didn't see right away the type inference pb. the emit(it) is the way to go

Comment: `data?.let { emit(it) }` as a one-line lambda for good style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but data clearly becomes `List<Bitmap>` after the null check

The compiler *could* make a smart cast there, but I guess currently it doesn't. Doing the simpler

```
if (data != null) { emit(data) }
```

should work. The usual reason to use `?.let` instead is if the value checked is a `var`, which doesn't apply here.

The reason `emit(it)` works is the type parameter inferred for `let`.

> The strange thing is that it compiles fine if I explicitly cast it like this `emit(data as List<Bitmap>)` (but again IDE shows that the cast is not needed).

That's not strange by itself, by the cast you are telling the compiler "it doesn't matter what you think type of `data` is, I know better". It would compile even if you had `data: Any?`.

The IDE showing the cast is unnecessary is the strange part and something I'd consider a bug (which could well be fixed by making the cast actually unnecessary).

Answer (score 0):

Just place a `?` after the `LiveData<List<Bitmap>>`. Looks like it's nullable. Or you can leave it as it is and change the `data?` to `data!!`

Comment: the idea was to check nullability before emitting the data

Comment: than my second statement comes in help

Answer (score 0):

Yes as you are adding the null safety on data

> data?.let {
>   emit(data)
>   }

But your function return type is not null so you need to add **?** with the function. So it can be a null value

```
val dishesBitmaps: LiveData<List<Bitmap>>? = liveData {
    val data = getDishesBitmaps()
    data?.let {
        emit(data)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data?.let {
    emit(data)
}
```

This block of code translates to

```
if (date != null) emit(data) else null
```

If you want return null safety object use elvis

```
data?.let {
    emit(data)
} ?: /**code if data is null**/
```